# Knockout.js - how to view the resulting html

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

My project uses knockout template to render html, so my html file contains just a bunch of knockout syntax and javascript functions. After I open the html in a browser, it shows the regular content that people would normally see on a webpage. My question is, how to I view the HTML source of that displayed page?

To be precise: For example, a full html source code is here and you can test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.1.0.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName()"></strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>

<p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>

<script type="text/javascript">


function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();   //call the observable as a function with ()  
    }, this);

}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the result, I see on the browser the following:

==========

First name: **Bert**

Last name: **Bertington**

Full name: **Bert Bertington**

==========

I need to see the **resulting** source html for this html for debugging purposes. However, if I right-click on the page and show source code, I would just see the html code that I wrote, not the one that is rendered by the browser. Note that the example above is simplified; my actual code is quite big and sophisticated and I need to see the result as html tags for debugging. So, what I need to see (for code inspection) is something like this:

```
<p>First name: <strong>Bert</strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong>Bertington</strong></p>
<p>Full name: <strong>Bert Bertington</strong></p>
```

Comment: Chrome prints out the rendered html, it might keep the data-binds as well, but it shows the rendered html

Comment: where and how do I see the rendered html code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your browsers developers tool. In Chrome this would be F12. They should have a tool to let you inspect the actual rendered HTML. In Chrome it's in a tab called `Elements`. From there you can look at the HTML expanding and collapsing nodes as needed. There is also a tool (the magnifying glass) that lets you select and element on the screen directly and it will show you the corresponding bit of HTML in the console.

Failing that, a simple `document.body.innerHTML` will dump the entire rendered HTML. You can do that from the debug console too.

A simple example, in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4z5tdLf3/), using Chrome (other browsers have similar functionality):

- Hit F12
- Select the Elements Tab
- Click the magnifying glass icon
- Click in the results window on one of the elements
- Notice the *rendered* HTML in the console:

```html
<!-- Original -->
<div data-bind="foreach:items">
    <div data-bind="text:$data"></div>
</div>

<!-- Rendered -->
<div data-bind="foreach:items">
  <div data-bind="text:$data">one</div>
  <div data-bind="text:$data">two</div>
  <div data-bind="text:$data">tree</div>
</div>
```

Now if you want a "clean", non-live version of the rendered text (one that won't be databound), then you ought to be able to just copy the html to a new element and remove the `data-bind` attributes. For example, using jQuery (although it can no doubt be done with vanilla JS):

```js
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();   //call the observable as a function with ()  
    }, this);

}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

var s = $("#source").html();
var t = $("#target");
t.html(s);
t.find("[data-bind]").removeAttr("data-bind");
$("#html").text(t.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Original data-bound</h4>
<div id="source">
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>

<p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>
</div>
<hr/>
<h4>Non-live rendered copy</h4>
<div id="target">
</div>
<hr/>
<h4>Raw rendered HTML</h4>
<div id="html">
</div>
```

Note this isn't entirely fool-proof as it won't find bits of knockout that aren't in data-bind attributes. If I'd use `<!-- ko foreach:items -->`, for example.

Comment: In chrome, the Elements tab only shows my original html and javascript, not the rendered html. Quick question: can I something like a simple javascript statement in chrome debugging? Say, I want to see *document.body.innerHTML*.

Comment: And I just tried *document.body.innerHTML*; it just dumps the original html as well.

Comment: @Simo: the elements tab shows the HTML that is rendered *on the page*. If it's not what you expect then it's because *you aren't rendering it*. You probably have an error somewhere. As for `document.body.innerHTML`, why don't you try in in the console and see what happens?

Comment: Hey Matt. Did exactly what you said, still see the original code, not rendered. I put the entire html file in my question above; do you mind testing it?

Comment: Sorry for the silly question: where do I find the spy glass? Where is it located? Or is it an extenal tool that I need to install?

Comment: In the developers console, it on the far-left. There is the spy-glass, the button for "device mode" (looks like a cell phone) then the tabs `Elements`, `Network`, `Sources`,...etc

Comment: Finally got it. Thanks!